# How to use client side validation with remote => true rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Normally we can use many ways to use ajax with validation like using `validate` plugin or using plain ajax(no rails ajax) like below

data using ajax requests

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

In your situation it can be something like that.

```
$('#your_form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  /* Email validation here.*/
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
  });
});
```

But, I wish to use client side validation with Real Rails ajax . Please help how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you'd like to use [this gem](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations)

**UPDATE 1:**

Since you want to do this through ajax, validation can be handled through you controller.

```
# Let's assume your remote request hits index

def index
 @object.create(params[:object])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.js
 end
end
```

Now, define an index.js.erb in the relevant views folder & render

```
<% if @object.new_record? %>
 alert("Failed to upload record: <%= j @object.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
```

Comment: thanks rahul, but I suppose just for a form and for an email validation on a form in the project, I should not use this gem. This is supposed to be used when we use it throughout the project.

Comment: Ok, firstly, if you're using remote, the data is sent to your controller. So your validation can be done there. In your controller add a format.js in your respond_to block & render your error through a javascript file.